# Druid search query does not return case sensitive results

Tags: druid, pydruid

I don't want to return the records whose one dimension (name) does not have a case sensitive value say "ALEX". However, it returns the result. For example:

```
{                                                                                                                                                        
  "queryType": "search",                                                                                                                                 
  "dataSource": "users",                                                                                                                   
  "intervals": ["2020-12-01T02:00:00\/2020-12-01T02:30:00"],                                                                                             
  "pagingSpec":{ "threshold":100},                                                                                                                       
  "searchDimensions": [                                                                                                                                  
    "name"                                                                                                                                             
  ],                                                                                                                                                     
  "query": {                                                                                                                                             
    "type": "contains",                                                                                                                                  
    "case_sensitive": true,                                                                                                                              
    "value": "ALEX"                                                                                                          
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  "granularity": "all"                                                                                                                                   
}
```

Now, even though I don't have ALEX anywhere in the database, it shows the count of records containing "Alex" case insensitive.

One more question - Does druid support exact match for value case? It returns me records whose value is contained in the values of a dimension. I want to return the records whose value matches exactly as in query.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `caseSensitive` instead of `case_sensitive`.